# growing EBS RAID volume

Tags: raid, amazon-ec2, mdadm, amazon-ebs

I've created a RAID0 configuration with two 1GB EBS volumes, mounted at `/dev/md0` using `mdadm` and formatted with `XFS`
Next, I copied some files over to fill the volume to around 30% of its capacity (of 2GB)

I then created snapshots of the volumes using `ec2-consistent-snapshot` and created volumes of the said snapshots but specified the volume size to be 2GB (effective doubling the capacity on each disk)

I then spun up a new instance, assembled the RAID0 configuration on `/dev/md0` from the 2 volumes mentioned above and mount it to `/vol`

`df -hT` showed /vol as 2GB (as expected)

Now I ran `sudo xfs_growfs -d /vol`. The command completed normally but reported `blocks changed from 523776 to 524160` (only!) and `df -hT` still showed /vol as 2GB (instead of the expected 4GB)

I rebooted, remounted, reassembled the RAID but it still reports the old size.

EDIT: trying to grow the RAID using `mdadm --grow` yields `mdadm: raid0 array /dev/md0 cannot be reshaped`

Is there any other way I can grow a RAID0 array?

Comment: I can *really strongly* urge you not to do this, R0 is bad enough when you're using DAS, but using in a situation where the SLA is already wooly enough and where outages DO occur is I believe only asking for trouble. If you want so extra performance at least R10 them.

Comment: I assume that EBS is a abstraction over a highly-redundant data store. If this is true then R10 would not add extra value.

Comment: EBS is not highly-redundant - it's entirely possible to lose a volume. Per their docs: "As an example, volumes that operate with 20 GB or less of modified data since their most recent Amazon EBS snapshot can expect an annual failure rate (AFR) of between 0.1% – 0.5%, where failure refers to a complete loss of the volume."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to create new set of volumes from scratch (2GB each) and assemble a new RAID0 configuration in parallel (say, /dev/md1). Copy the files from one raid volume (/dev/md0) to the other (/dev/md1).

Comment: yup! thats what I thought. In the absence of any other replies, I'll accept yours and move on. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the --update=devicesize option when assembling your array.  ie:

```
    mdadm --assemble --update=devicesize --scan
```

or

```
    mdadm --assemble --update=devicesize <device>
```

However, this requires that you are using at least v1.1 metadata, which puts the superblocks on the front of the devices.  If you expand volumes using v0.90 or v1.0 metadata, you will have to recreate the array to put the new superblocks at the end of the devices.  This is non-destructive to filesystems as long as you use the same options when creating the array as you did originally.